# Downloading multiple files that have their URLs stored in a file but with wildcards inside the file using wget

Tags: downloads, wget

I have to download multiple log files from an internet page but only the files that have a specific name that I have on my file:
In my file called "net" I have the following names but not the address of the https:

```
bbys
autn
aubg
axpv
```

....

On the https page they appear:

```
.../log/bbys_20191202.log  
.../log/prne_20201202.log
.../log/autn_20201202.log 
.../log/aubg_20171202.log 
.../log/axpv_20141202.log
```

From the https page I would like to download only the log files that are contained in my "net" file:

```
.../log/bbys_20191202.log  
.../log/autn_20201202.log 
.../log/aubg_20171202.log 
.../log/axpv_20141202.log
```

Is there a way to use the wild card but invoking the "net" file.
I have tried

```
wget -r --no-parent -A '*.log' -i net
```

but is downloading the entire directory.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Code blocks are shown by using 1. Newline 2. 4 spaces before command. 3. Newline

Comment: Thank you for arranging the post